# Error File path denied, but the file is in the folder(One time success other error) C#

Tags: c#, path, access-denied, file-not-found, abbyy

I want to apply `OCR ABBYY` with 4 photos at same time in `C#` (I have the function for this conversion).

1) I have file `Identite.jpg` (image source).

2) I have an executable file: `Cutting.exe`, which cuts `Identite.jpg` into 4 parts: `Prenom.jpg`, `nom.jpg`, `Date.jpg` and `numcin.jpg`.

3) Then, I apply the function of `OCR` to these 4 files.

Sometimes I have a successful result, but other times I get the following error:

```
D:\CINPROCESSING\Prenom.jpg FileNotFound
```

However, this file is located here!!

I have tested this by manually executing the file `Cutting.exe`. When I execute my `C#` application, and the result always successful - yielding the 4 files.

But when the function of `OCR` comes, the `FileNotFound` error appears (even though this file is in the folder)!

I have even executed the file in `C#` with *Full Access: administrator*:

```
Process.Start(@"D:\Cutting.exe");
        ProcessStartInfo kk = new ProcessStartInfo();
        kk.Verb = "runas";
```

I also tried adding in my application the element: `app.manifest`, and I modified the `requestedExecutionLevel` with `'requireAdministrator'`:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Always same problem! Please, how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested if the file is existing or not ... it is not existing ..
I have found the solution:
I added :

> Thread.Sleep (3000);

between Step 2) and Step 3)

And now it works well

Very thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   string filePath = @"D:\Cutting.exe";
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "mspaint.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = filePath;
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks,

No..the cutting of my picture to 4 fields ..ERROR!!
Cutting.exe do not execute!
"mspaint.exe" ..cutting.exe is not file Paint!

Comment: Oh, my fault... filePath it`s your .exe . Ok. How you choose .jpg?

Comment: When the Cutting.exe execute...The result is 4 pictures: prenom.jpg, nom.jpg,...

After that i  called the 4 pictures : to apply the function OCR ..
Here the problem: prenom.jpg FileNotFound!!!! 
despite it exist !!!